# What does #! operator mean in Linux?

Tags: shell

while following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) tutorial I found a command

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

I don't understand the meaning of #!/bin/sh. I tried to search it but google removes the ! symbol from search results.

**What does `#!/bin/sh` mean here?**
Please help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash

Comment: It is a convention specifying which shell program should interpret the rest of the file.

Comment: Attention Downvoter!  Can you help me understand I could get an answer to my question? Can you help me understand what is the better way to ask this question?  If not, you are just promoting ignorance... so that the ignorant remain ignorant as if they don't have the right to know what they don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#!` specifies the program with which the script should be executed if you not explicitly call it which any

in your case,  if you call your script with: `<scriptname.sh>` Linux will execute it as `/bin/sh <scriptname.sh>`

Comment: And if anyone's wondering, it's called shebang (alias hashbang)